# PHP: if charset mismatches (htmlentities UTF-8) viewed by client as ISO-8859-1 (or vice versa)

Tags: php, xss, encoding, unicode

**Short Question:**

Question: Could any security vulnerabilities arise if a server runs htmlentities as UTF-8 but the client views the results as ISO-8859-1?

*Assumption:* No vulnerabilities exist when one consistent charset is used

---

**Detailed Question:**

Question: Could any security vulnerabilities arise if the server htmlentities a ISO-8859-1 string as UTF-8? (and the client interprets the result as ISO-8859-1?)

(e.g. `$results = htmlentities($iso_8859_1_string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")`

Assuming everything is coded in such a way that no vulnerabilities arise when just one character set encoding is consistently used.  (Ignoring if $results = empty string).

Perhaps if `$iso_8859_1_string` could contain any value, the results would be treated as either invalid UTF-8 (and return ""), or as valid UTF-8. For valid UTF-8, the UTF-8 sequences would be escaped as expected, but how would the results be viewed on the client interpreting the result as ISO-8859-1?  The characters results in the 0 - 127 range being escaped as expected (same as "US-ASCII"), some characters would resolve into html entities and could be displayed as expected. Are there valid UTF-8 characters in the higher 128+ range which do not resolve to html entities?  Would the client just see a bunch of garbled/garbage text/symbols but no characters which would cause the web browser to execute code or switch into a code execution context? (e.g. no tag characters such as '<' '>' symbols)?  (Assuming the $results are put into a "content context", and not in an "attribute value" or a "script" body).

Is this right line of thinking?

---

**Note**: I believe I've already worked out the *vice versa* case (i.e. if the server htmlentities a UTF-8 string as ISO-8859-1 and the client interprets the result as UTF-8)

(e.g. `htmlentities($utf8_string, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1")`)

Answer: My guess is no security vulnerability on the client (for htmlentities as ISO -> client reads as UTF-8) because:

- In ISO-8859-1, characters in the range :

  - 0-127 (US-ASCII): are encoded exactly the same way in UTF-8,
  - 160 -> 255 in ISO-8859-1 would all be encoded as HTML entities,
  - leaving just the 128-159 character range..., but according to Wikipedia's UTF-8 specification, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description, all UTF-8 bytes that are in the 128+ range are all part of "multi-byte sequences" which comprise a "leading byte" which is always 192 or higher, and "continuation bytes" in the 128+ range.  Thus, the `htmlentities($utf8_string, ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1")` could not output any "leading bytes" needed by UTF-8 to generate valid multi-byte sequences. So any characters in this range would appear in UTF-8 as a ? (i.e. an invalid character) due to not seeing any "leading byte".

I think this solves my question for the other direction.

---

Real-world situation: A PHP 5.3.x server with security backports uses ISO-8859-1 as the default encoding. Starting with PHP 5.4, UTF-8 is the default encoding.  http://php.net/htmlentities. I'm wanting to determining if the code works properly in either an all UTF-8, or all ISO-8859-1 environment, and ensuring there are no automatic security holes caused by encoding mistakes/mismatch.

I feel like I can rest assured that only usability is affected, but not security in these specific cases.

Comment: Only thing I can find is http://zaynar.co.uk/docs/charset-encoding-xss.html but even then I don't think it is related in your situation.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm aware, there's no security issue.

The "dangerous" characters in HTML (less-than, greater-than, ampersand, single quote, double quote) all have identical byte values under UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 (and virtually every other encoding you're likely to encounter, with the exceptions of UTF-16, UTF-32, and EBCDIC).  As a result, escaping them in one encoding will escape them in the other encoding as well.

The reason this holds true is that the vast majority of character encodings, including UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1, are "ASCII plus additional characters", and the structure of an HTML document only uses characters in the ASCII portion of the encoding.

Comment: So the only real question is "are there any dangerous non-ASCII characters": if the answer is "no", then any encoding which encodes ASCII verbatim (e.g. the ones you mention) is safe. This question is answered briefly in the last sentence of this answer; is there any need for expanding?

Answer (score -2):

for as long as i know, aslong as your PHP scripts (i.e. forms) use the filter for htmlspecialchars() and strip things like weird symbols and backslashes, there wouldnt be a security risk, atleast from my perspective.

forcing a charset to be used by the clien is an option for us paranoid people though, along with the basic stuff i just named.

Comment: You're forgetting attacks such as [XSS with UTF-7](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200704/xss_with_utf7.html)  where sequences such as `+ADw-script+AD4-` will bypass filters and encoding routines that work in UTF-8 and will be rendered as `<script>` on a client reading the page as UTF-7.

Comment: thats why i reccomend the basic protection against these attacks but filtering those characters out, since that stuff is only lethal on server-side, in PHP

Comment: That's my point, they won't be filtered out if encoded by UTF-7. XSS is client side.

Comment: it doesnt get filtered out client sided?.....gotta dig into that one :3